# XXXXXXXXRepository' that could not be found In Spring boot application (3.0.0Version)

Tags: spring, spring-boot

My Spring boot application working fine with out any issue with spring boot version 2.7.6 version. The security venerability team has been raised issue with spring-web 5.3 version. Now i just upgrading the spring-web version from spring-web5.3 to 6.X version.

For this, I have done the below changes.

Changed the java version 1.8 to 17.
Spring boot starter parent jar upgrade the from 2.7.2 to 3.0.0, and then spring 6.X framework downloading automatically.
Build was successful, But when i run the server getting error as above.

Am I going correct way? is there any alternative way to migrate the spring-web jar from 5.x to 6.x?

```
Issue description:
-----------------
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
※ネバネネネぶぶぶぶぶぶぶぶ※メススメネススメポポポン
Description:
Parameter 0 of constructor in jp.co.metlife.mis.service.EventLogService required a bean of type 'jp.co.metlife.mis.repository.EventLogRepository' that could not be found
The injection point has the following annotations:

@org-springframework.beans. factory.annotation. Autowired(required-true)
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type "jp.co-metlife.mis.repository-EventLogRepository' in your configuration.
```

Changed the java version 1.8 to 17.
Spring boot starter parent jar upgrade the from 2.7.2 to 3.0.0, and then spring 6.X framework downloading automatically.